# A depth version of a conjecture of Yamagata

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a finite-dimensional $K$-algebra.
Recall that the grade of an  $A$-module $M$ is defined as the smallest $i$ such that $\operatorname{Ext}_A^i(M,A) \neq 0$ and the depth of $A$ is defined as the maximum of the grades of the simple $A$-modules.

Let $X_n$ be the set of non-selfinjective finite dimensional $K$-algebras with $n$ simple modules.

Define $\operatorname{domdim}(n):= \sup \{ \operatorname{domdim} (A) \mid A \in X_n \}$ and $\operatorname{depth}(n):= \sup \{ \operatorname{depth}(A) \mid A \in X_n \}$ for natural numbers $n \geq 1$.

The strong Nakayama conjecture predicts that every finite dimensional algebra has finite depth and the Nakayama conjecture predicts that every finite dimensional non-selfinjective algebra has finite dominant dimension.
Yamagata gave the stronger conjecture that $\operatorname{domdim}(n)$ is finite for all $n.$

> Question: Is $\operatorname{depth}(n)$ finite for all $n$?

That is: Can there be finite dimensional algebras with a fixed number of simples having arbitrary large depth?
Note that a positive answer would imply Yamagata's conjecture and several other important homological conjecture, so the question here mostly asks for a possible counterexample.

Note that for other homological dimension such as the global and finitistic dimensions, the analogue definitions have the property that $\operatorname{gldim}(n)$ and $\operatorname{findim}(n)$ are infinite.